# Does python len() faster than just counting

Tags: python, implementation

As per my understanding (but actually didn't test) calculating len of string (for example) with len() func takes less time than simply calculating number of chars in the same string cause len() somehow optimized.
  Is it the case and how it works in simple words?

The follow up practical question probably would be : " If possible is it a good practice in general to use something like len(string) for early false detection in code in terms of O(code) complexity"

Thanks

UPDATED.
Originally I didn't present any code so now just adding it and hope that would be a bit representative if I haven't mess a lot with it.

```
import timeit


def len_test(arr):
    return len(arr)


def manual_count(num):
    ln = 0
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        ln += 1
        i += 1
    return ln



for i in range(1000, 10000, 1000):
    count = i
    array = [_ for _ in range(i)]

    t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt='len_test(array)', setup='from __main__ import len_test, array', number=count)
    t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt='manual_count(count)', setup='from __main__ import manual_count, count', number=count)

    print('i: {}, len:{:.8}, count: {:.8}'.format(i, t1, t2))

i: 1000, len:0.0001499, count: 0.12168087
i: 2000, len:0.000327363, count: 0.53221788
i: 3000, len:0.000449699, count: 1.167412
i: 4000, len:0.000595823, count: 2.1061223
i: 5000, len:0.000762714, count: 3.2617024
i: 6000, len:0.000937534, count: 4.8079927
i: 7000, len:0.001076862, count: 6.5171025
i: 8000, len:0.001222231, count: 9.3587468
i: 9000, len:0.001398561, count: 11.686714
```

Comment: What does the alternative counting code look like…?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "early false detection"?

Comment: In general: The`len()` function calls the `__len__()` method of the object and the implementation there *can* be and often is more efficient than the trivial counting approach.

Comment: AFAIR for cPython boils it all down to "reading a variable", where some kind of PyObject keeps track of the current length of the sequence. The closest thing I found was https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html But perhaps others could help, filling the gaps ;)

Comment: Because Python `str` objects keep track of their length as an internal attribute. It is accesible by calling `mystring.__len__()` or `len(mystring)`

Comment: Hi @deceze, answering both questions I would say :
count = 0
for char in string:
    count  += 1
but guess that "in" statement may have difference.

As for the second part: classic problem is to check if string '(()' contains balanced  braces. And I'm trying to understand if I should go straight with some kind of stack solution or should actually check "if len(string) % 2: return False."

Comment: Checking for balanced parentheses where your string contains *only* parentheses is a pretty useless practical problem. It's good for teaching/learning, but in practice you'll more likely have expressions which contains parentheses *and other stuff*, so your `% 2` check would be pointless there anyway…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

test = [x for x in range(1000)]
count = 0

start = timer()
len(test)
end = timer()
print(end - start)

start = timer()
for i in test:
    count += 1
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

**Returns**:

```
2.643069343567298e-06

213.7110354941546e-06
```

If `test = "This is a test string."`

**Returns**:

```
2.2654880087719696e-06

1.0572277374269745e-05
```

Comment: The idea behind `timeit` is that you're supposed to use `timeit.timeit` to time things, not call the timer manually.

Comment: I've added some tests. Does it serve the purpose?
And still it's seems to me the true that len is faster I interesting in knowing why it is so?

Comment: @СергейНиколаевич `len()` has a time complexity of O(1), whereas counting each element using a loop has a time complexity of O(n).  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 3):

I checked it in a real condition and counting was 2 time or more faster than len().

My code that read two CSV format texts and then calculate number of lines is this:

```
import time
import csv

start_time = time.time()

psr = open('e_psr.txt')
cpr = open('e_cp.txt')

csv_psr = csv.reader(psr, delimiter=',')
csv_cp = csv.reader(cpr, delimiter=',')

csv_cp_copy = []
csv_psr_copy = []
r=0
e=0
for row in csv_psr:
    csv_psr_copy.append(row)
for row in csv_cp:
    csv_cp_copy.append(row)
e = len(csv_cp_copy)
r = len(csv_psr_copy)
psr.close()
cpr.close()

print(e,r)
print("\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and when I replaced `len()` with a simple counter in for loop (`e += 1`) the result significantly changed.

return with len():

```
10000 10000

--- 0.13390278816223145 seconds ---
```

return with counter:

```
10000 10000

--- 0.05642294883728027 seconds ---
```